# can't use @can @endcan spatie package on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So, i have installed spatie package for role and permission without install laravel/ui.
when i type

```
php artisan permission:show
```

it's work and show my permission and role
But, when i try to use `@can ..... @endcan`
it's can't work. I don't know what's wrong.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item{{ request()->is('/') ? ' active' : '' }}">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
          </li>  
          @if(session()->has('LoggedUser'))
          <li class="nav-item{{ request()->is('daftarmobil') ? ' active' : '' }}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/daftarmobil">Daftar Mobil</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item{{ request()->is('contact') ? ' active' : '' }}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          @can('manage-car')
          <li class="nav-item{{ request()->is('products') ? ' active' : '' }}">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/products">Manage - Car
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          @endcan
          <li class="nav-item{{ request()->is('login') ? ' active' : '' }}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="logout">Logout
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        @else
        <li class="nav-item{{ request()->is('login') ? ' active' : '' }}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        @endif
      </ul>
    </div>
```

can anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign permission to user or any role which belongs to user, after that you can user @can